# php reading file list of webaddresses and searching the source of those sites for string

Tags: php

I've created this script to search through ny2.txt which contains a list of web urls (currently just 1 line)
http://campersbarn.com

I then want to loop through each line and get the source of that site.
Last, I'm checking if the text krgrpowered exists in the site.

This is from the Error-log

```
[08-May-2014 08:10:55 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home4/millipg7/public_html/limitedtee/test/test.php on line 8
[08-May-2014 08:10:55 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://campersbarn.com
): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home4/millipg7/public_html/limitedtee/test/test.php on line 8
```

If the content in ny2.txt is 'http the url dot com' or "http the url dot com"
The php executes super fast but nothing happens...

```
<?php

$lines = file('ny2.txt');
$fh = fopen("result.txt", 'w');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $url) {
  $html = file_get_contents($url);
  if (strpos($html,'krgrpowered')!==false)
   fwrite($fh,$url."\n");
} 
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean that `'http the url dot com' or "http the url dot com"`? Are you quoting the URLs?

Comment: Check wether `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your php.ini and wether your server can actually resolve `campersbarn.com`: `nslookup campersbarn.com`.

Comment: if works without its {} ?

Comment: Please don't edit the question and remove log format. Proper format makes it more readable and it highlights what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the trailing line feeds you can use [rtrim()](http://php.net/rtrim):

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $url) {
    $url = rtrim($url);
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
```

But I recommend that you simply use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag so [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) does not append them in the first place:

```
$lines = file('ny2.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

They're of little use anyway.

Comment: Might aswell add SKIP_EMPTY_LINES too.

Answer (score -1):

Check a var_dump of the $url you're generating. It may be as simple as whitespace/newline characters breaking your URL. Try:

```
$html = file_get_contents(trim($url));
```

Or if you want to be very thorough:

```
$html = file_get_contents(rawurlencode(trim($url)));
```

I notice a little space after the URL in your error message (http://campersbarn.com ), so that's probably all it is.